# UPS vs Surge Protector regarding short circuits and quality of power

Tags: electrical, electricity, surge-protection

I did research before posting and it seems a UPS filters power so that it is constant and “filtered” additionally it seems to be able to protect against short circuits. Does a surge protector have these same benefits except for the fact that it can provide power during an outage!

This is what I found regarding UPS and short circuits:
“ Uninterruptible power supply (UPS) systems ensure critical loads have continuous and quality power. ... Proper coordination of protective devices in the UPS distribution system means that only the fuse or breaker directly upstream of a fault (short circuit) will operate to clear the fault.”

Is this paragraph accurate and does this fact apply to surge protectors except the power, during power outages?

Do surge protectors filter power so that it does not have spikes and makes the power filtered and constant?

Comment: Do surge protectors filter power ? No They just clamp over-voltage spikes. They also do not protect from over current surges on startup. They do however need a suitable size breaker to trip if the voltage spike draws excess current.  These are cheap but effective solutions in power strips for lightning, but they do wear out  after so many zaps and often no wear indication

Comment: Is there protection from short circuits?

Comment: That's what circuit breakers do ( or fuses)

Comment: Don’t surge protectors have a circuit break/ fuse so in theory would it protect devices on it from short circuits damaging them?

Comment: If you are referring to power strips, yes and MOV's or TVS components no.

Comment: A power strip like a belkin BN450M from Amazon for instance. Would that have short circuit blocking capability that would protect devices on it. Should of specified sorry.

Comment: As in blocking I mean it prevent a short circuit but block the excess amps/volts etc from the devices connected to it

Comment: 2 surge-only outlets on BN450M . Shorts come from load faults